# How to add screen sharing to my app

Tags: apache-flex, applet, video-streaming, red5, screen-capture

Are there any off the shelf components for adding a screen sharing feature to my app?

I've built real time text chat for a group chat room - now I'd like to have a button where a user can share their screen with the other members of the chat.

Basically, I'm looking for a way to add this feature as easily as possible, hopefully using a service provider to help:

Client:
The client can be Flash or Java applet based (whatever works) 
- I'm currently investigating this: http://code.google.com/p/red5-screenshare/
but would love any others options you may know of

Server:
Are there any hosted live Red5/Adode FMS providers out there, that I could point a client to?
I've also seen Adobe LiveCycle Collab - but I have no Flash/Flex experience.  Are there any providers that I can point a client to and they'll take care of the streaming bit.

For example, Opentok works well for video sharing, but they only support sharing a webcam and not a user's desktop.

Any thoughts on this would be most appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently started using Bloomfire and they have the most seemless screencapture experience. I suggest you investigate how they do it, maybe it's even licensable.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the response.  I've sent them an email to see if it is licensable.  It looks like they are not really a platform for developers to hook into.  Not sure.  Any other off the shelf components for screen sharing you can think of?

Comment: @JimJones Hey Jim did you ever receive a reply from them? Or figure out how to implement a seamless screen recording tool into your web app?

Answer (score 0):

You might check out http://sourceforge.net/projects/dimdim/ as well. They were acquired by SalesForce not too long ago, but the open source version lives on. There is an API to integrate DimDim into your apps, but now with the SalesForce.com acquisition I'm assuming you'll have to run your own DimDim server to accomplish this.